# Helm's Tiller container gets x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, kubernetes, certificate, kubernetes-helm

I'm running Kubernetes on an AWS (version 1.5.2). I have installed helm using

`helm init --node-selectors="nodeType=master"`
forcing it running on the master.

When I try to run `helm list` i get the following error `Error: Get https://192.0.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%3DTILLER: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

The logs from the tiller container (seems the issue is from the tiller to Kubernetes-api):

```
E0219 08:15:12.546100       1 config.go:330] Expected to load root CA config from /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt, but got err: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory  
E0219 08:15:12.547957       1 config.go:330] Expected to load root CA config from /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt, but got err: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory
[main] 2018/02/19 08:15:12 Starting Tiller v2.7.0 (tls=false)  
[main] 2018/02/19 08:15:12 GRPC listening on :44134  
[main] 2018/02/19 08:15:12 Probes listening on :44135  
[main] 2018/02/19 08:15:12 Storage driver is ConfigMap  
[main] 2018/02/19 08:15:12 Max history per release is 0  
[storage] 2018/02/19 08:20:47 listing all releases with filter  
[storage/driver] 2018/02/19 08:20:47 list: failed to list: Get https://192.0.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps?labelSelector=OWNER%3DTILLER: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Is there a way to configure tiller to ignore the untrusted certificate?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Kubernetes cluster isn't properly configured. Usually there is a CA certificate for every pod in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` that allows pods to communicate with the API server.

The first two lines in your log show that no such file could be found: 
`Expected to load root CA config from /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt, but got err: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory`.

Comment: thanks Lukas for the response, we are using Kube-proxy for API communication. Doing the same http get with the proxy address from the tiller container works.  
I will look into adding the certificates. thank you.

Comment: @AmitMatsil Does your Kubernetes API server use HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: it's using HTTP